# Multiple level lookup field

Tags: sql, delphi, lookup, master-detail

I have three tables, Countries, Department & Cities, Cities table contains a foreign key to Department table PK index, and Department contains a foreign key to Countries Table PK Index for example :

COUNTRIES TABLE RECORDS

```
PK=1   |   NAME = France
```

DEPARTMENTS TABLE RECORDS

```
PK=1   |   NAME=Ile de France   |   COUNTRYKEY=1
PK=2   |   NAME=Bouches du Rhone   |   COUNTRYKEY=1
```

CITIES TABLE RECORDS

```
PK=1   |   NAME=Paris   |   DEPTKEY=1
PK=2   |   NAME=Marseille   |   DEPTKEY=2
```

So, i want display a city form with all details, name department country

I actually use lookup field to display the department name but what about to display also in the city form the "COUNTRY" name which is only included on Department Table as foreignkey ??? i mean is there a way to display a lookup field of a lookup field ? as a beginner a detailled code would be appreciated, Thanks to all

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  And `JOIN` again.

Comment: As a beginner, you *really* need to find more tutorials on using SQL, and in general writing SQL queries. This is extremely trivial stuff. Along the lines of asking how to use the brakes on your car, for comparison. It doesn't even matter whether you're using a foreign key or not. Joining other tables in a SQL statement is just one of the core fundamental basics of SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SELECT d.NAME AS Department_Name, ct.NAME as CITY, cn.NAME AS COUNTRY
    FROM DEPARTMENTS d
    LEFT JOIN CITIES ct ON d.PK = ct. DEPTKEY
    LEFT JOIN COUNTRIES ON d.COUNTRYKEY = cn.PK
```

You might need an `WHERE` clause added and possibly a `ORDER BY` at the end, but you didn't indicate that.

Comment: I only want to display the whole CITIES Table with all details about it, CITY DEPARTMENT AND COUNTRY names, so i think there s no need for a WHERE Clause, i will try your code

Comment: @AlvenCode I feel the mention of `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clauses was only rhetorical, considering `JOIN` is what you need for this, while being such a common and basic part of SQL to begin with. It was sarcasm.

Comment: Then you will want to make the `CITIES` table your main one, not the `DEPARTMENTS` as I did above. But I think my answer should point you in the right direction.

Comment: @JerryDodge: Yes, my comment at the end was rhetorical, but not sarcasm. I genuinely want to help someone who is new to programming. But I agree with your comment to the OP, they need to get a tutorial. ;)

Comment: The join work perfect, thanks, answer will be accepted .... just please now i have an joined table, and i want for example edit a record from it and see changes only apply to cities table how can i proceed ?

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Now give your new question a try and if you get stuck post it as a new question here.